# matplotlib minus sign in tick labels has bad formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, xticks

Matplotlib appears to use the "correct" unicode character for a minus sign in tick labels if they are set automatically. However, if I try to set them manually, it appears that it instead uses a hyphen (which looks way too small and generally bad). How can I manually change the tick labels while retaining the correct minus sign? Here is an example of a comparison between the automatic and the manual setting of the labels.
Automatic:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(np.arange(-50,51,10), np.arange(0, 101, 10))
plt.xticks(np.arange(-50,51,10))
```

Manual:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(np.arange(-50,51,10), np.arange(0, 101, 10))
plt.xticks(np.arange(-50,51,10), np.arange(-50,51,10))
```

Here is the comparison of the output
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/euLmy.png

The real reason that I care about this is because I want to set the labels to values that are **different** from the default ones. I am running matplotlib version 3.2.2.

Comment: Your code does not work: `np.arange(-50, 51, 10)` contains 11 elements while `np.arange(100)` has 100 elements. On my side, the minus sign is correct. Could you post a running code so we can work on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the standard tick labels, [the minus signs are converted automatically to unicode minus signs](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/unicode_minus.html).
When changing the tick labels, the numbers are converted to strings. Such strings don't get the automatic replacement to unicode minus signs. A solution is to do it explicitly:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot(np.arange(-50, 51, 10), np.arange(11))
plt.xticks(np.arange(-50, 51, 10), [f'{x}'.replace('-', '\N{MINUS SIGN}') for x in np.arange(-50, 51, 10)])
plt.show()
```

[image: comparison plot]